# Does quantificational logic replaces syllogistic?

Tags: logic

If so, does it mean we should always use quantificational logic since it combines both syllogistic and proportional logic? Also, Is there any other logic which further builds on quantificational logic?

Comment: There are many logics out there, and none of them replace the others-- the choice of which logic is most appropriate depends on the context.  What is the context of your asking the question?  Do you have a proof of some kind that you would like to formalize?

Comment: @MichaelDorfman: Actually, I was reading this page on [syllogism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism) It says that "syllogism was superseded by first-order predicate logic" So, I was wondering if that is right.

Comment: Yes, that also says "but syllogisms remain useful", and "[citation needed]"; as always, take pronouncements on Wikipedia with a grain of salt.

Comment: I think that wiki page is referring to the fact that for a long time (basically until Frege) philosophers thought that *all* propositions could be expressed in syllogistic form, if only one worked hard enough at it. That is no longer the belief.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Syllogistic logic is one of the things that one does with quantificational logic, just as one occasionally works with arithmetic of integers when working in real analysis or group theory (both of which generalize integer arithmetic). We do not take special note of the structure of syllogisms, because they are only a special case of the usual rules of inference; because we have more flexible tools, we do not put as much effort into memorizing what syllogistic formulae are valid or invalid, except as examples of valid or invalid reasoning in general.

In the following, I will let x:A denote that an object x takes a property A.

**All A are B:**  ∀x: (x:A) ⇒ (x:B)

**Some A are B:** ∃x: (x:A) & (x:B);

**Some A are not B:** ∃x: (x:A) & ¬(x:B);

**No A is B:** ∀x: (x:A) ⇒ ¬(x:B).

Syllogistic reasoning can be performed as it was traditionally, albeit with extra instantiation and generalization steps, and often using rules of inference such as modus ponens and modus tollens. Here are two typical examples of syllogistic reasoning, where the first two lines are classic syllogistic premisses, and the final line is the classic syllogistic conclusion.

*Example 1.*

> **P1.** ∀x: (x:Human) ⇒ (x:Mortal)
>   *Premise — gloss: all humans are mortal* 
>   **P2.** Socrates:Human 
>   *Premise — gloss: Socrates is human* 
>   **UI.** (Socrates:Human) ⇒ (Socrates:Mortal)
>   *universal instantiation — gloss: if Socrates in particular is human, then he is mortal*
>   **MP.** Socrates:Mortal
>  
>   *modus ponens — gloss: therefore, Socrates is mortal*

*Example 2.*

> **P1.** ∀x: (x:Rabbit) ⇒ (x:Furry)
>   *Premise — gloss: all rabbits have fur* 
>   **P2.** ∃x: (x:Rabbit) & (x:Pet)
>   *Premise — gloss: some rabbits are pets* 
>   **EI.** (Flopsy:Rabbit) & (Flopsy:Pet)
>   *existential instantiation — gloss: consider Flopsy, a (generic) pet rabbit*
>   **UI.** (Flopsy:Rabbit) ⇒ (Flopsy:Furry)
>   *universal instantiation — gloss: if Flopsy in particular is a rabbit, then Flopsy is furry*
>   **MP.** Flopsy:Furry
>   *modus ponens (with a conjunctive simplification) — gloss: therefore, Flopsy is furry*
>   **CI.** (Flopsy:Pet) & (Flopsy:Furry)
>   *conjunctive introduction (with a conjunctive simplification) — gloss: therefore, Flopsy is a furry pet*
>   **EG.** ∃x: (x:Pet) & (x:Furry)
>   *existential generalization — therefore, some pets have fur*

Syllogistic reasoning is therefore a special case of quantificational logic; it is a framework in which one can confidently reason syllogistically, without being limited only to syllogisms. But one should not feel absolutely restricted to using quantificational logic, or any particular logic; it suffices to use some logic which is both effective and reliable for coming to usable conclusions.